# Wordpress template footer not displaying as it should

Tags: css, wordpress

I've just done a wordpress template and the footer isn't 100% width like it should be.

http://79.170.44.113/yorkshirecouriers.co.uk/?page_id=8

Any ideas why?

Am I missing a div ending anywhere?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a missing closing `</div>`. See [[Invalid] Markup Validation of  79.170.44.113 yorkshirecouriers.co.uk ?page_id=8 - W3C Markup Validator](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A//79.170.44.113/yorkshirecouriers.co.uk/%3Fpage_id%3D8&doctype=Inline&ss=1&group=0&user-agent=W3C_Validator/1.654). Scroll down in the validation report to see line numbers and source code.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting style for footer from a CSS file. Pull up styles.php and view settings for footer. Or you can put footer in a  only without any sort of styling.